# What are the alternatives for high order component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Coming with php background not sure how to implement a design with reusable code,

the problem:
we are creating a react/redux app with a lot of similar components that share a lot of functionality... I've read about HOC but was wondering if there are another solutions that would help in this situation!?

Answer (score 1):

There is something called `function as child components` (not sure if that's an official name but anyways)

The basic idea is that react accepts functions as child components, so for example instead of the react redux's `connect` HOC component you could do something like this

```
<Connect mapStateToProps={myMapper}>
  {({ users, isLoading })} => {
    //renders the user
}}
```

and the connect implementation is quite simple compared to a HOC.

```
render() {
  return this.props.children(
    this.props.mapStateToProps(this.state)
  )
}
```

You can check a pretty interesting video about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcVAq3YFiuc

Comment: I think the hip kids are calling them `render props` but honestly it's just HoCs by a different name I feel.

Comment: Indeed, I think the main advantage is really simplicity. Normal HOC implementations generally involve using inheritance, passing around propTypes and defaultProps and so on. Those `render props` are a lot more explicit and simple IMO

Answer (score 0):

Component inheritance. 
You can extend one component from some `ComponentBase` to share some functionality between them. But actually its different way from creating HOC. Hoc just allows you to pass some props to child, inheritance give you an ability to share methods and state.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/blob/master/src/_shared/PickerBase.jsx 
Here is a Base component from my project